# \pagedir TRT with pgfpages cause an incorrect result (shift out of page)

Tags: luatex, right-to-left, pgfpages, shipout

Using `\pagedir TRT` with  `\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]` from `pgfpages` package produce logical pages to be shifted out of page.

Same issue with layouts `4 on 1`, `8 on 1`, `16 on 1`.

```
% lualatex 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]

\begin{document}

\pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT

\Huge 

Page 1
 
\newpage

Page 2

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Update 22/08/2020

I find a method to shift logical pages using `\pagerightoffset`, the problem is for every layout I need to add manually the  amount of  shift.

### Example with 2 on 1 layout landscape page

```
% lualatex 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}


\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,landscape]

\begin{document}

\pagerightoffset = .55\pgfphysicalwidth % <--
\pagedir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT 

\Huge 

Page 1
 
\newpage

Page 2

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've opened an issue for this on pgfmorepages at https://github.com/loopspace/pgfmorepages/issues/4

Comment: With the `2 on 1` layout that you have, what _should_ the order of logical pages be on the physical page?  In the image, you have Page 1 on the left with Page 2 on the right.  With RTL, shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @AndrewStacey yes with TRT page first page should be on the right and the second on the left.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd have to make a new layout that lays out the pages RTL.

I change one line in the `2 on 1` layout from:

```
center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
```

to:

```
center=\pgfpoint{-.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
```

I'ts possible to do this with `xpatch`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\expandafter\xpatchcmd\csname pgfpages@layout@2 on 1\endcsname
  {center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}}
  {center=\pgfpoint{-.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}}
  {}
  {}
```

For the layouts with more pages per page, you'd need multiple calls to `xpatchcmd`.

### Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{rtl 2 on 1}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperwidth} % landscaped by default
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperheight}
  \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
  \def\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout{1}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=2,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth,%
    current logical shipout=\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout%
  }
  \ifdim\paperheight>\paperwidth\relax
    % put side-by-side
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{-.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}% <- Shift second page to left hand side
    }%
  \else
    % stack on top of one another
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
  \fi    
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{rtl 2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]

\usepackage[bidi=basic-r,nil]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
      
\begin{document}

\Huge 
نص من اليمين الى اليسار

 الصفحة الأولى 1

\newpage

\Huge 
نص من اليمين الى اليسار

الصفحة الثانية 2

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, this means that I need also to create an rtl layout for 4 on 1,  8 on 1,  16 on 1 layouts?

Comment: @SalimBou, since the layouts are hard coded  to be LTR, I can't see any obvious alternative. Perhaps it would be possible to use `xpatch` if you dig through the what `\pgfpagesdeclarelayout` actually defines.

Comment: `\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{center=\pgfpoint{-.25\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}}` can be used to solve the issue with `2 on 1`  layout.

Comment: It looks like in LTR document the origin of coordinate is at left lower corner but in RTL the origin change with layout `2 on 1`, `4 on 1`, .....

Comment: We need also this patch of `\pgfpages@buildshipoutbox` command as reference point in TRT page is at lower right point unlike TLT  page `\xpatchcmd{\pgfpages@buildshipoutbox}{\pgfpoint{-.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}{\pgfpoint{.5\pgfutil@tempdima}}{}{}`