# Globally reverse direction of x coordinate in pgfpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, pgfkeys, right-to-left

I have this example of an RTL document which I need to revert x system coordinate, with `tikzpicture` environment I have used `\tikzset{every picture/.style={xscale=-1}}` to do that, but with `pgfpicture`
env I can't find how to do a global inversion of x coordinates

```
% lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=graphics]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={xscale=-1}}

\begin{document}

before
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{3cm}{1cm}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}
after

\bigskip
before
\begin{pgfpicture}
%\pgftransformxscale{-1}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{3cm}{1cm}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{pgfpicture}
after

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The output of mine is different from your compiling with `lualatex`!! but when I disable the two lines `arabic` and `bidi` and compile it using `pdflatex` it is similar to your output but `after` and `before` has been reversed.

Comment: This transformation  `\tikzset{every picture/.style={xscale=-1}}` applies to all the figures and therefore the second is transformed twice, so it is identical.

Comment: @AndréC the transformation is applied only for `tikzpicture` environment not for `pgfpicture`.

Comment: Indeed, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I don't think that there is a sensible hook. Write a RTLpgfpicture environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think if I can reverse x coordinate system in pgf the solution can  be used to solve this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/559267/54817