# Is it geometry or pgfpages bug?

Tags: geometry, updating, pgfpages

With `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` inserted in `2 on 1` pgfpages layout  produce an unexpected result.
I have updated latex last week, before that this problem did not appear

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]
 
\newpage

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is how it looked like before the update.

[image]

Comment: and what do you expect instead?

Comment: Before updating there are two frames.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer With TeX Live 2019 it is as expected.

Comment: @SalimBou I took the liberty of adding the output one gets with TeX Live 2019. I guess that the problem is with `pgfpages`.

Comment: Thanks @egreg for completing my question.

Comment: @egreg I guess the problem is with the latest LaTeX release breaking tons of third-party packages.

Comment: @HenriMenke I disagree. Unfortunately PGF is known to break things when hooking in `\shipout` using nonstandard methods.

Comment: @egreg I had no texlive 2019 here, but saw it now on overleaf.

Comment: Another problem with a recent download of TexStudio is described in the comments of the post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568586/trying-to-add-a-separator-in-the-table-of-contents

Comment: @HenriMenke we will add something to the firstaid package which will handle this. This will be a temporary measure until LaTeX has a suitable configuration point that pgfpages could use instead of patching \shipout.

Comment: @IChekhov how should installing texstudio cause any issues. That comment on the link more sounds like a user who does not know that latex and editor are two completely separate things. Kinda like when users ask how the install packages in texmaker

Comment: @HenriMenke it is not breaking *tons* of packages, but if you want to get to cleaner interfaces then yes, those packages that had to work around issues in the past may have to adjust to the new existing interfaces and the no longer existing internals they overwrote. But given that adding the hook management was a huge step (and improvement toards standard handling) I would claim we managed quite will in getting it off without breakage -- on the whole.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue has been temporarily resolved by adding a fix to `firstaid` (as part of the LaTeX format). This has been send off to CTAN so it should reach the major distributions today or tomorrow and from that point onwards should work again as before.

As @AndrewStacey observed the kernel needs to provide an interface to take over control at the very end of building up a page just prior to shipping it out to the dvi/pdf file as an applications like `pgfmorepages` want to add further control on what happens at this stage (instead of simply shipping the page out).

However, this can't be done through a "hook" of the new hook management as this is not about adding additional code (where several packages could add code and the only question to resolve is in what order) but it is about changing the process and only one process can be executed.

The model here has to be one where  one process can be swapped in for another but only one process is ever active.  My tentative term for that is that of a "configuration point" and we are currently working on iron out the interfaces and concepts for that.  Once that is available we will work with package maintainers how to apply them and then take out the current "firstaid".

Comment: Thanks for quick fix, I have updated `firstaid` and everything is fine.

Answer (score 13):

*This is not an answer, it is a description of the problem.  I am assured that this will be addressed soon in a proper manner.*

The way that `pgfpages` (and its extension, `pgfmorepages` - which I maintain) works is by saying to LaTeX, "You build the *entire* page exactly how you want to, then *just before* you ship it out, I'll take it and squirrel it away for later consideration.".  Then at a later point, they say "Right, now I want you to ship out *exactly* this page.".

From that description, it is hopefully clear that `pgf[more]pages` needs to interrupt the shipout routine at the very, very last moment.  The page needs to be complete, including headers and footers, and backgrounds, and borders.

From poking around in the `latex.ltx` code, I can see that the LaTeX team have been working behind the scenes to streamline the LaTeX core.  Part of that involves putting *hooks* at various points to allow packages to *hook in* to various routines in a more orderly fashion than has been previously possible.  I guess that the purpose of this is to sort out the mess that is conflicting packages who all try to redefine the same command, environment, or routine.

With regard to the shipout routine, therefore, the new LaTeX kernel adds in its own code at the point of shipping out a new page which provides access to all of these hooks.  One of which, by the way, is used by `geometry` to put the frame around the page (`geometry` doesn't *know* this - thanks to the wizardry of the LaTeX team an awful lot of packages should *just work* without modification).

So at the moment we have a race condition in that both LaTeX and `pgf[more]pages` are trying to insert their code into the shipout routine and both work by replacing `\shipout` by their code.  The order that *should* happen is that LaTeX's code works first and then `pgf[more]pages` second.  Unfortunately, as LaTeX is loaded before `pgf[more]pages`, actually what happens is that `pgf[more]pages` is executed first and then the LaTeX code.  This means that code such as `geometry`'s `showframes` is only executed when the page is *actually* shipped out and not when `pgf[more]pages` stores the page.  This is why the frames are incorrect.

What appears to be needed is a "Right before shipout" hook that allows `pgf[more]pages` to swoop in at the last minute. That currently doesn't exist, however from comments from the LaTeX team it would appear that they are aware of the issue and will address it shortly.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewStacey  for this very detailed answer.

Comment: We will add a similar correction to the firstaid package. Please do **not** spread this advice around. If such code is added more than once people will end in loops (such as one gets if one loads both pgfpages and pgfmorepages).

Comment: what's this remark about the 18th centry supposed to mean? care to elaborate Andrew? As Ulrike said we will resolve your race condition in a day or two (CTAN distribution permitting). Mid-term we will provide an orderly way to extend the page building logic in a reliable manner (just like the hooks already do for other parts) without the need to low-level alter primitives  or internal macros.

Comment: Sorry @FrankMittelbach, that was meant as a joke that clearly misfired. I've removed it. The timeline of the resolution wasn't clear to me from the comments to the question so I thought I'd dig into it to see what was going on. I hoped my comment at the outset made it clear that I didn't view this as a *solution*, just a temporary fix while a proper solution was figured out.

Comment: @AndrewStacey but why didn't you ask? You know where you can find us.

Comment: @AndrewStacey a smiley would have helped (me at least) the way written it could be interpreted as we are moving backwards a lot. Anyway, to the point in question. Please do not add that temp fix to the package. We fix the issue in firstaid and once a proper interface is ready we discuss with you how to best update pfgmorepages -- ok?

Comment: @SalimBou As Frank and Ulrike have said that this will be addressed soon, and being aware of the dangers of code that only works for a short stretch of time, I've removed the code from my answer. Hopefully the explanation is still of some value, but it probably no longer qualifies as worth an accepted mark. Once this is fixed properly someone will post an answer here saying so and you should accept that answer.

Comment: @AndrewStacey ok, I have posted a question about using `pgfpages` in case of TRT pages (luatex engine) 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559267/pagedir-trt-with-pgfpages-cause-an-incorrect-result-shift-out-of-page  
 To obtain a right result with TRT page   we need to invert x coordinate in every `\pgfpoint`, is there a possibility to add solution of the issue in upcoming versions  of `pgfmorepages` ?

Comment: @FrankMittelbach, FWIW I saw the "18th century" comment and it certainly struck me as humor, and if anything an an acknowledgement that the Latex team was doing a lot of work and making a lot of improvements. I don't know AndrewStacey's nationality, but that sort of humor is common in the US.

Comment: @dedded Andrew is a limey. (Apparently some consider that term derogatory; it is not intended that way. I know the bloke in question, and he's a nice kind of person.)